# Scope/Roles claim not available in the Client Credentials access token

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

After fetching the `access_token` (`grant_type=client_credentials`) from `login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`, I get back:

```
HTTP 403
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "fa788422-6868-4ab3-9ded-5f076138bda2",
      "date": "2019-04-02T11:24:30"
    }
  }
}
```

When I [decoded the token](https://jwt.io/), it actually does not have an `SCP` or `ROLES` key in the body (opposed to what I've seen from the token I read from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer))

I read many docs/blogs on this, and all of them pointed to adding "Microsoft Graph's Application permissions", and then getting an admin consent on them. I got the consent after adding required permissions (`Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder`, etc):

[image: Admin consent on required permissions]

Code:

```
const escapedScopeUri = querystring.escape(
  `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`
);
const secretKey = querystring.escape(
  azureApplicationConfig.clientSecret
);
const requestBody = `client_id=${azureApplicationConfig.clientID}&client_secret=${secretKey}&scope=${escapedScopeUri}&grant_type=client_credentials`;

const authReqOptions = {
  method: `POST`,
  uri: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
  body: requestBody,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  }
};

rp(authReqOptions) // rp = request-promise module
  .then(async authRes => {
    console.log(authRes);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // do something with err
  });
```

Now, this is not the complete code, but it should give an idea of what is being done.

After `authRes` is available, I decoded the token information (where the scope is not available). This is the returned info:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "ext_expires_in": 3600,
  "access_token": "returned token"
}
```

and the decoded token body info:
[image: decoded token body information]

Additionally, I have added `appRoles` in the manifest (not sure if this is the correct format):

```
{
  //...
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
      "description": "Trying to make app as Reader",
      "displayName": "Reader",
      "id": "4e76a3f3-86c9-4186-aa1d-c22ccc167326",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "lang": null,
      "origin": "Application",
      "value": "reader"
    },
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
      "description": "Trying to make app as Admin",
      "displayName": "Admin",
      "id": "f3f3b2f0-3203-45fa-89e0-17a9c9b4ee73",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "lang": null,
      "origin": "Application",
      "value": "admin"
    }
  ]
  //...
}
```

Still, things have not worked out.

Comment: Did you register this as a v1 or v2 application?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I registered this as a v2 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot request Client Credentials from the `/common` tenant. Since you're not providing an email address (as you would with Auth Code or Implicit), there is no way for AAD to discover which tenant you're looking to obtain a token for.

You need to supply either your tenant URI (`domain.onmicrosoft.com`) or the `id` (a GUID issued to each tenant when it is created):

```
const authReqOptions = {
  method: `POST`,
  uri: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${your-tenant-uri-or-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
  body: requestBody,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, I'll try it out and get back.

Comment: Yes it works. I just changed `/common` to `/tenant publisher domain uri` and it gave back the correct token.

Comment: The reason why I used `common` was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin. If you look at the description of `tenant` here, it says `If you don't know which tenant the user belongs to and you want to let them sign in with any tenant, use common`. Now, it does not say the same if you scroll to `Get a token` part on the docs page. I just supposed that the former statement was true always. My bad!